# jQuery $(this) not working when inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple function that copies some html, and places it in another div.
If I put the code for the function in the click event it works fine, but when I move it into a function (to be used in multiple places) it no longer works.
Do you know why this is?

If I console.log($(this)); in the function it returns the window element.

```
 function addHTMLtoComponent () {
        var wrapper = $(this).closest(".wrapper");
        var component = $(wrapper).find(".component");
        var componentCodeHolder = $(wrapper).find('.target');   

         $(componentCodeHolder).text(component.html())
      //console.log($(this));
 }

 $(".js_show_html").click(function () {
     addHTMLtoComponent();
 });
```

codepen here - http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/ebe7a5a45f2c5bbe58734411b03e180e

Should i be referencing $(this) in a different way?

Comment: You need to pass `$(this)` to your function: `function addHTMLtoComponent($this) {}`, and call it with `addHTMLtoComponent($(this))`

Comment: the function does not know who the caller is so it does not know who `this` refers to, you need to pass it (as a parameter) yourself

Comment: Also, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more info on why `this` works the way it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: `$(".js_show_html").click(addHTMLtoComponent);`

Comment: The problem here isn't really related to jQuery - it's the way `this` works in JavaScript.  The linked duplicate goes into excruciating detail of how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since you called the function manually the function doesn't know the "this" context, therefore it reverted back to use the window object.

```
$(".js_show_html").click(function () {
     addHTMLtoComponent();
 });

// Change to this

$(".js_show_html").click(function () {
     // the call function allows you to call the function with the specific context
     addHTMLtoComponent.call(this);
 });
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: brilliant! Thanks mate! :D

Answer (score 6):

Regarding other answers, i need to put the easiest one:

```
$(".js_show_html").click(addHTMLtoComponent);
```

Comment: Interesting! Does this work because there is not wrapper function absorbing `this`?

Comment: @cyberbit jQuery arranges for `this` to refer to the element involved in the event.

Comment: @Pointy Right, I was just pointing out that the OP's solution had `addHTMLtoComponent` wrapped in another function, so the context got overwritten. Upvoted for simplest solution.

Comment: This is definitely the right solution, but OP should still learn about how `this` works

Comment: Thanks mate! I listed the other answer as correct as I used that solution - because I wanted to call further functions within the click function. 
But your way of doing it is helpful and easy! Thanks!

Comment: Apparently in this case there is something provided as a parameter. It seems to be the HTML tag which triggered the event. I didn't find any documentation regarding it - can you help me and provide any link to some documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 4):

`this` in the context of the `click()` event is the element clicked. In the context of the function `addHTMLtoComponent` `this` no longer is a reference to the element clicked.

Try passing the clicked object to the function to maintain the object reference.

---

```
function addHTMLtoComponent ($obj) {
    var $wrapper = $obj.closest(".wrapper");
    var $component = $wrapper.find(".component");
    var $componentCodeHolder = $wrapper.find('.target');
    $componentCodeHolder.text($component.html());
}

$(".js_show_html").click(function () {
    addHTMLtoComponent($(this));
});
```

Comment: I know this answers the question, but shouldn't `addHTMLtoComponent` be called with the value of `this`? e.g. `addHTMLtoComponent.call(this);` rather than blindly passing jQuery objects around?

Comment: @DavidBarker If the function is written to always accept a jQuery object, and is documented as such, why not pass it one?

Comment: I have to agree with David. The advantage of using `this` instead of `$(this)` is that it supports everything the jQuery constructor supports, including both elements *and* jQuery objects (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: @DavidBarker it's not blindly passing anything, more so it is specifically passing a jQuery object. using `this` or `$(this)` doesn't really matter or solve the problem but explaining what `this` is, contextually, is what the OP is looking for, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the element as parameter to this function.
eg:

```
<div onclick="addHTMLtoComponent ($(this))"></div>
```

Comment: You don't have to and anyway it is different than setting context but not wrong

Comment: Not wrong... but the inline part, that's truly horrid!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could consider is that `addHTMLtoComponent()` could be made into a jQuery function itself:

```
$.fn.addHTMLtoComponent = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var wrapper = $(this).closest(".wrapper");
      var component = $(wrapper).find(".component");
      var componentCodeHolder = $(wrapper).find('.target');   

      componentCodeHolder.text(component.html())
    });
}
```

Now you can call it like any other jQuery method:

```
$(".js_show_html").click(function () {
   $(this).addHTMLtoComponent();
});
```

The value of `this` in a jQuery method will be the jQuery object itself, so you don't need to re-wrap it with `$()`. By convention (and when it makes sense), jQuery methods operate on all elements referred to by the root object, and they return that object for further chained operations. That's what the outer `return this.each()` construction does.

Inside the `.each()` callback, you've got a typical jQuery callback situation, with `this` being set successively to each member of the outer jQuery object.

Comment: Why pollute the fn space just for that?

Comment: @DuD. why not? It's not sacred or anything, and so long as one is fairly careful with method names collisions are not very likely. If this is important functionality for an application it's not a bad idea. Of course, that's a matter of opinion, and you're correct that it *does* live in the flat jQuery method namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The special keyword `this`, when you call a function by itself, is the `window` object (which is what you observed). For the behavior you need, just add a parameter to the function that loads the appropriate context:

```js
 function addHTMLtoComponent(context) {
   var wrapper = $(context).closest(".wrapper");
   var component = $(wrapper).find(".component");
   var componentCodeHolder = $(wrapper).find('.target');

   $(componentCodeHolder).text(component.html())
     //console.log($(context));
 }

 $(".js_show_html").click(function() {
   addHTMLtoComponent(this);
 });
```